# Draw rotated rectangles

Tags: android

I drew a rotated rectangle and I wanted to draw another one with the same size just above the first one and I can't get this done somehow the second rect don't get the right position
I give him the same left and right and change the bottom to the top of the first rect and the top to - top-top of the first rect
Here is the code for the first rect draw (the second draw is in my laptop and it is not near me)

```
int offset = 200;
int left = width/2;
int top = height/2;
int right = left + offset;
int bottom = top + offset;

canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(45, left + offset/2, top + offset/2);
canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Why don't you just do canvas.rotate(45, rect1.centerX(), rect1.centerY());

Comment: You are right didn't thought about that but can you answer my question?